# Get object annotated with Qualifier from Dagger graph

Tags: java, android, dagger, otto

Unless a singleton object in graph is annotated with a Qualifier we can just call:

```
graph.get(Bus.class);
```

If this object is annotated in the module definition with a Qualifier then it will throw IllegalStateException.

Is there a better way of retrieving that object from the graph than:

```
public class BusWrapper {
    @Inject
    @MyQualifier
    Bus bus;
}
```

and

```
graph.inject(new BusWrapper()).bus;
```

I have a set of graphs (one graph for each account). Separate bus for each account graph and one app scoped bus (annotated with different Qualifier).
Once I receive a GCM sync request message I need to retrieve the bus from the correct graph to pass the sync request.

Comment: Think I would create and provide a BusFactory and associate a id/name for each Bus. Then when GCM arrives, do something like `busFactory.getBusByName('nameOfBus').`

Comment: @cYrixmorten That isn't at all safe or statically analyzable, all both of which Dagger and qualified injections provide.

Comment: What object is this code inside of that it can't just inject the all of the qualified `Bus` instances directly and then switch/ifelse between them?

Comment: @JakeWharton Do you mean the the BusWrapper should have a member for each of the types of the Bus? I get it - it will work. The place where I need that is out of Account scope (there is one service for all incoming messages). It actually looks like application.getMapOfAccountGraphs.get(account).inject(new BusWrapper()).bus.post(Event). A the moment I only need one type of bus and the code above is doing what I want. I was just wondering if there was a way to retrieve specific type of Bus with get() method and/or the snippet above is OK. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performing annotated instance lookups via `.get()` is not supported.

I couldn't find a good reference post to cite. The closest is [this one](https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/401#issuecomment-39677414):

> Dagger 1.0 is definitely designed around having robust entry-point/injectable objects, rather than using ObjectGraph like a big annotated map.

Basically, `.get()` was designed to be used for grabbing the root instance from your object graph under which all dependencies would be `@Inject`ed normally.